# Simple conditional probability question?

Tags: probability

So I know that for events $A_1, ..., A_n$ we have $P(A_i) + P(\neg A_i) = 1$ and that $P(A_i) = \sum_{j \ne i} P(A_i|A_j) P(A_j)$. This later one is bayes rule so then is it true by consequence that $P(A_i| A_j) + P(A_i | \neg A_j)$ = 1?

So an example would be if 3 green marbles, 2 blue and 1 red in a box. Whats the probability of getting a red marble while there is at least one blue marble in the box?

$P(red |blue \ge 1) = 1- P(red | blue =0) = 1- 1/4 = 3/4$?

Answer (score 0):

The assertion that $\Pr(A_i|A_j)+\Pr(A_i|\lnot A_j)$ is in general not correct. A similar-looking equation, $\Pr(A_i|A_j)+\Pr(\lnot A_i|A_j)=1$ is correct.

Here is a simple example. Toss a coin once. Let $A_j$ be the event we got a head, and let $A_i$ be the event we got $17$ heads. The two conditional probabilities $\Pr(A_i|A_j)$ and $\Pr(A_i|\lnot A_j)$ are both $0$. If this is too simple an example to be persuasive, experimentation will soon give you more complex examples.

Comment: What about the marble problem then? How would I get that conditional probability?

Comment: Once the experiment is precisely described, I can probably compute the probability. If my guess about the intended problem is correct, the solution will not involve Bayes' Rule.